# Difeerence in padding for bool

Tags: c

```
struct home
{
 uint32_t calss;
 uint8_t name;
 float keyl;
 bool flag;
 uint16_t me;

};
```

Can someone help explain why uint8_t is padded 3 bytes but the bool is only padded a byte.

Comment: It depends on your compiler, compiler option and processor architecture. You should give those information.

Comment: What makes you think that it is? What does surprise/wonder you about it?

Comment: Note: in general, to reduce padding, I recommend compiling with `-Wpadded` in `gcc`/`clang`, which will warn whenever the compiler adds padding. Then its a simple matter of rearrangement.

Answer (score 3):

This is because `float` (requesting 4-byte alignment) is after `uint_8` and `uint16_t` (requesting 2-byte alignment) is after `bool` in this case.

Swapping them will result in swapping the number of padding.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

struct home
{
 uint32_t calss;
 uint8_t name;
 float keyl;
 bool flag;
 uint16_t me;

};

struct home2
{
 uint32_t calss;
 uint8_t name;
 uint16_t keyl;
 bool flag;
 float me;

};

int main(void) {
    struct home h;
    struct home2 h2;
    printf("home:\n");
    printf("calss : %p\n", (void*)&h.calss);
    printf("name  : %p\n", (void*)&h.name);
    printf("keyl  : %p\n", (void*)&h.keyl);
    printf("flag  : %p\n", (void*)&h.flag);
    printf("me    : %p\n", (void*)&h.me);
    printf("home2:\n");
    printf("calss : %p\n", (void*)&h2.calss);
    printf("name  : %p\n", (void*)&h2.name);
    printf("keyl  : %p\n", (void*)&h2.keyl);
    printf("flag  : %p\n", (void*)&h2.flag);
    printf("me    : %p\n", (void*)&h2.me);
    return 0;
}
```

[Example output](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6VSOjqRGB13OeHLb):

```
home:
calss : 0x7ffcd0f9b4a0
name  : 0x7ffcd0f9b4a4
keyl  : 0x7ffcd0f9b4a8
flag  : 0x7ffcd0f9b4ac
me    : 0x7ffcd0f9b4ae
home2:
calss : 0x7ffcd0f9b490
name  : 0x7ffcd0f9b494
keyl  : 0x7ffcd0f9b496
flag  : 0x7ffcd0f9b498
me    : 0x7ffcd0f9b49c
```

Answer (score 1):

The first field is padded 3 bytes because the next field (a `float`) requires four byte alignment, and so, three bytes are needed to align it to a multiple of four bytes.  The second field (the `bool`) has one byte of padding for the same reason: the next field (an `uint16_t`, 16 bit wide) requires 2 byte alignment, and so only one byte is needed to get a 2 byte alignment.

For the final padding, you compute the `struct` alignment as the largest alignment of the largest field in the structure, and padding is included to make an array of such `struct`s correctly aligned.  The structure's `sizeof` will reflect this final alignment, so an array of such structures will have all cells aligned with just aligning the first one.

If you reorder the `struct` fields making the two one byte fields to be together and before or after the 2 byte data, then you'll get a structure with no gaps.  This is because after the one field aligned field there's another one byte field, and the next field (the two bytes field) is already aligned to a multiple of 2 address, so no padding is necessary.  After the 2 bytes field, the alignment is already 4 bytes aligned, so the next field will be immediately after.